# Como receber um json na Controller e passar para array object

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, preciso pegar na Controller os objetos filtrados para exportar para relatório. estou fazendo o envio por json usando Ajax, porem eu não sei se objeto esta sendo enviado para Controller,dei um console.log(response) e aparece o seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se esta chegando na controller não sei como o pegar, se eu dou decode_json da error 500
segue o código:

**JS**

```
function ajaxExportar(colaboradores) {
    var token = $("#token").val();
    var json = stringToJson(colaboradores);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/colaborador/exportar',
        type: 'POST',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        },
        data: {
            'json': json,
            '_token': token
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('a').addClass('disabled');
            $("#overlay").faLoading({
                "type": "add",
                "icon": "fa-refresh",
                "status": 'loading',
                "text": false,
                "title": ""
            });
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var json = (response);
            $("#overlay").faLoading("remove");
            $('a').removeClass('disabled');
            if (json.error) {
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Erro!',
                    text: json.error,
                    icon: 'fa fa-warning',
                    type: 'error',
                    styling: 'fontawesome'
                });
            }
        },
        statusCode: {
            //erro de autenticação em caso de logout
            401: function() {
                alert("Necessário fazer login novamente!");
                window.location = "/home";
                //                window.location.reload();
            },
            //erro de servidor
            500: function() {
                alert("Erro servidor");
            },
            //not found
            404: function() {
                alert("Arquivo não encontado");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Controller**

controller em teste para pegar o json.

```
public function exportar() {
        $json = Request::input('json');

        $colaborador=json_encode($json);


         print_r($colaborador);
         die();
}
```

**Route**:

```
Route::post('colaborador/exportar', 'Cadastro\ColaboradorController@exportar');
```

Comment: tente o seguinte: `json_decode($json, true);` no seu controller e ao invés de die retorne o valor e veja no "network" qual o valor que está recebendo

Comment: deu erro 500 :jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/colaborador/exportar 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: e no network deu : json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: certo, o que acontece é que você está recebendo o valor de Request::input('json') como um array, não como uma string

Comment: me dê um momento que vou testar aqui

Comment: tem um exemplo do que você recebe na variável `colaboradores`? na function  ajaxExportar(colaboradores)?

Comment: outra coisa, qual versão do laravel você está usando?

Comment: na view ? onclick="ajaxExportar('{{$colaboradores}}');" recebo ja da controller filtrar os $colaboradores

Comment: estou usando a versao laravel 5

Comment: Versão 5.1,5.2 ..?

Comment: extamente versão 5.0

Answer (score 6):

Altere sua função no `Controller` para que fique dessa forma, teste o que é impresso no `console.log` do `callback` de sucesso e poste aqui nos comentários.

```
public function exportar(Request $request){
    $dados = $request->except('_token');
    return response()->json($dados);
}
```

De toda forma, parece que seus dados estão sendo enviados até o `Controller`, sendo assim você pode interagir com eles através do `foreach`:

```
public function exportar(Request $request){
    $dados = $request->except('_token');
    foreach($dados['json'] as $obj){
        echo $obj->id;
        echo $obj->idCargo;
    }
    // return response()->json($dados);
}
```

Comment: Foi colocado como resposta o que comentei rs?Tinha uma resposta com um conteúdo bem similar, acho que o autor removeu

Comment: Não sei, não vi outra resposta e nos comentários da pergunta não está, mas se é parecida deve ser certa hehe

Comment: Sem problema. Comentei  pois achei similiar e imaginei que pudesse ter sido colocada com esse post (não vi  se você era moderador)

Answer (score 1):

achei a solução, vim compartilhar com vocês. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Controller

```
public function exportar() {
  $json = Request::input('json');
    $ids = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
        $ids[$i] = $json[$i]['id'];
    }
    $cheque = new Cheque;
    $cheques = $cheque->whereIn('id', $ids)->get(); //aqui posso fazer oqquiser agora que tenho os objetos ja formados
```

}

JS recebo da view um array objetos

```
function ajaxExportar(cheques) {
var token = $("#token").val();
//    var json = stringToJson(colaboradores);
var json = $.parseJSON(cheques);
//    console.log(json);
$.ajax({
    url: '/cheques/exportar',
    type: 'POST',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    ContentType: 'text',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    data: {'json': json, '_token': token},
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('a').addClass('disabled');
        $("#overlay").faLoading({
            "type": "add",
            "icon": "fa-refresh",
            "status": 'loading',
            "text": false,
            "title": ""
        });
    },
    success: function (response) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(response);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = json.file;
        a.download = json.name;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
        $("#overlay").faLoading("remove");
        $('a').removeClass('disabled');
        if (json.error) {
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Erro!',
                text: json.error,
                icon: 'fa fa-warning',
                type: 'error',
                styling: 'fontawesome'
            });
        }
    },
    statusCode: {
        //erro de autenticação em caso de logout
        401: function () {
            alert("Necessário fazer login novamente!");
            window.location = "/home";
 //                window.location.reload();
        },
        //erro de servidor
        500: function () {
            alert("Erro servidor");
        },
        //not found
        404: function () {
            alert("Arquivo não encontado");
        }
    }
});
```

}